# Example implementing the Chain Rule in a textbook by Charles Chapman Pugh

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule, pushforward

I am asking for help interpreting an example in a textbook. The author gives two functions from different dimensions of Euclidean space, and he precisely describes the image of arbitrary elements under these functions, but he does not state the arbitrary elements in the domains.

Here is the example from Chapter 5. Maybe someone has a different edition of the textbook.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f = (x,y,z)$ and $g = w$ where
$$w = w(x,y,z) = xy + yz + xz$$
and
$$x = x(s,t) = st, \quad y = y(s,t) = s\cos{t} \quad z = z(s,t) = s\sin{t}.$$

a.) Find the matrices that represent the linear transformations $(\mathrm{D}f)_{p}$ and $(\mathrm{D}g)_{q}$ where $p = (s_{\circ}, t_{\circ}) = (0,1)$ and $q = f(p)$.

b.) Use the Chain Rule to calculate the $1 \times 2$ matrix $[\partial{w}/\partial{s}, \partial{w}/\partial{t}]$ that represents $(\mathrm{D}(g\circ{f}))_{p}$.

c.) Substitute the functions $x = x(s,t)$, $y = y(s,t)$, and $z = z(s,t)$ directly into $w = w(x,y,z)$ in order to get $[\partial{w}/\partial{s}, \partial{w}/\partial{t}]$, verifying the answer in Part b.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets a bit messy but we have the following...
$$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$$
$$f(s,t)=(x,y,z)=(st, s\cos(t), s\sin(t))$$

So the matrix which represents the total derivative of our map $f$ at the point $p=(s,t)$ would be...

$$(Df)_{(s,t)}=\begin{bmatrix}
    t &s 
\\  \cos(t)& -s\sin(t)
\\  \sin(t)& s\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Additionally, we have the map;
$$w:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$w(x,y,z)=xy+yz+xz$$

Which yields;

$$(Dw)_{f(p)}=\begin{bmatrix}
    (y+z)& (x+z)& (y+x)
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, by the chain rule, our map $D(w\circ f)_p$ would give us;

$$D(w\circ f)_p=D(w)_{f(p)}\circ D(f)_p=\begin{bmatrix}
    (y+z)& (x+z)& (y+x)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    t &s 
\\  \cos(t)& -s\sin(t)
\\  \sin(t)& s\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Letting $(s,t)=(1,0)$ gives us;

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 &1 
\\  1& 0
\\  0& 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0& 2
\end{bmatrix} $$

I'll leave it to you to confirm that;

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial s}& \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial t}
\end{bmatrix}_{(1,0)}$$

gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide the various derivative matrices for me.

Comment: Is this the worst way to pose this problem?

Comment: What is "$g$"? Notice that you don't mention it in your solution.

Comment: Here is how I would have defined the function $f$.

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is defined by $f(s,t) = (st, \, s\cos{t}, \, s\sin{t})$.

Comment: That would have been clear.

Comment: @user74973 I didn't mention $g$ because the problem stated that $g=w$ so it seemed redundant to switch back and forth. Also, the problem is, perhaps, slightly unclear if you haven't dealt with total derivatives before but once you are aware of of that concept then what the author wants becomes clear. Hope the answer was helpful...

Comment: Yes, your explanation is very clear. Thank you for your patience in typesetting the derivative matrices and the justifications for them.

Comment: You have one mistake in your solution. It seems to be just a typographical error. You need to delete ...

Comment: ...  "$(Dw)_{f(p)}$" in your calculation of $D(w\circ{f})_{p}$.